# Office 365 Security & Compliance Content Search not finding Keyword if among multi-selected Lookup column

Tags: office-365, lookup-column, multiple-values, compliance-center

**Setup:**

1. I created the following:

   - a *list* (named *Category*) at the top-level site,
   - a Lookup *site column (SC)* (named **Category**) on *Category*, **which allows multiple selections**, and
   - a *Document*-based *content type* (named **Categorized Document**) with the additional **Category** column added.
2. On the top-level site (*Parent*) AND on a subsite (*Child*), I added the **Categorized Document** *content type* to *Shared Documents* and removed *Document* from the list content types.
3. I mapped *RefinableString00* to the Crawled Property created for my site column (*ows_Category*).
4. I added three (3) items to the *Category* list, with *Title*s of "White," "Red," & "Blue."
5. I uploaded multiple documents to both *document libraries* and randomly chose *Category* values for some of them: each document has zero (0), one (1), two (2), or three (3) *Category* values.
6. In *Security & Compliance*, I created a *Content search* on `RefinableString00:White` and added filters on *File type equals any of* `doc; docx; xls; xlsx; pdf`:

   - `RefinableString00:White‎(c:c)‎‎(filetype="doc")‎‎(filetype="docx")‎‎(filetype="xls")‎‎(filetype="xlsx")‎‎(filetype="pdf")‎`

**Issue:**

When I run the query, it finds all of the documents from both *Shared Documents* libraries, **ONLY** where *Category*="White," not if it's "White" and something else.

**Question:**

**What do I change to make sure it finds all of the documents where Category includes "White," even if it also includes other values?**

### **Answer:**

Marko Tica's syntax was super helpful to getting me closer to the final answer:

`RefinableString00:{White}‎(c:c)‎‎(filetype="doc")‎‎(filetype="docx")‎‎(filetype="xls")‎‎(filetype="xlsx")‎‎(filetype="pdf")‎`

In the case of a string with spaces (e.g. *"Red and Blue"*), the following worked:

`RefinableString00:{Red}‎{and}{Blue}(c:c)‎‎(filetype="doc")‎‎(filetype="docx")‎‎(filetype="xls")‎‎(filetype="xlsx")‎‎(filetype="pdf")‎`

**Notes:**

1. Marko's answer included `{|…}` around the entire query, which is probably very helpful when working with Search. Security & Compliance's Content search wouldn't accept it, and it ultimately wasn't needed.
2. Marko's answer also wrapped the search text in `""`, which also returned no results. I haven't tested this with other 'Refinable' types, but my assumption is that because it's a `RefinableSTRING`, the quotes weren't needed to *type* the query. Even in the case of a string (e.g. "Red and Blue"), the quotes weren't needed; instead, wrap each word in the phrase with `{}` IN ORDER to search on the phrase.

Comment: Let us know if you find a solution because I am going to have to deal with this soon in a project...

Comment: Can you use the SharePoint Query Tool and check what the value for RefinableString00 is for a document which has more than one value in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this

```
{|ManagedProperty:{QueryVariable}}
```

Query would be something like this

```
{|RefinableString00:{"White"‎}}
```

[LINK](http://www.techmikael.com/2014/05/s15e03-query-variables-constant-trouble.html)

> Query variables with multiple values
>   Query variables can contain multiple values, and by using the syntax {|ManagedProperty:{QueryVariable}} or {|{QueryVariable}}
>
> The expansion will be made using the OR operator, and there is no
>   option for AND expansion. If a user has set the Ask me about field on
>   the user profile to: SharePoint, Search and Apps, then the
>   transformation
>
> {|{User.SPS-Responsibility.Name}}
>
> expands into
>
> ((SharePoint) OR (Search) OR (Apps))

**Working syntax**

```
RefinableString00:{White}
```

Comment: Did you try with {|RefinableString00:{"White"‎}}

Comment: Thanks, Marko! +50 for you because it was the most helpful.

Here's the actual syntax that worked:

RefinableString00:{White}

No {} around the whole thing, no "" around the value.